# Firebase Recycler View firstly showing blank page but when power off my mobile & open then showing data perfectly, no errors

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm creating app with Firebase implementation. Now I'm stuck with showing list of data using recyclerView. After using my code I have empty activity without any error in Logcat but when turn off my mobile power button and again start then data show on recycleView. Also one thing when I go another activity and open this activity then again show blank page. I need someone's help :(

This is my fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);

    // Initialize
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    list = new ArrayList<>();

          
    // For retrieve Chat User ID
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                receiveID = ds.getKey();

                // Restore Data on model class name UserDataInfo
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersData").child(receiveID);
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String userName = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("userName").getValue());
                        String userNumber = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("userPhone").getValue());
                        String userType = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("userType").getValue());
                        String userImage = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("userName").getValue());

                        info = new UserDataInfo(userImage, userType, userNumber, userName, receiveID);
                        list.add(info);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                // End
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });     
    adapter = new messageListAdapter(list, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class messageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<messageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<UserDataInfo> infoList;
Context context;

public messageListAdapter(List<UserDataInfo> infoList, Context context) {
    this.infoList = infoList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public messageListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_list_show_admin, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull messageListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final UserDataInfo userDataInfo = infoList.get(position);
    holder.Name.setText(userDataInfo.getUserName());
    holder.Number.setText(userDataInfo.getUserPhone());
    holder.whichType.setText(userDataInfo.getUserType());

    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ID: " + userDataInfo.getReceiveID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return infoList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView Image;
    TextView Name, Number, whichType;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.UserImage);
        Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        Number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Number);
        whichType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.WhichType);
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Linear_layout);
    }
}
}
```

my Firebase DataBase setup:

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSZ9d.png)

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHGPv.png)

Comment: So what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: data is not loaded in the recycleview firstly. But when I off my mobile power button & open then data loaded